# Add a class when the maximum number of elements have been selected

Tags: jquery

The code I have below adds a class "disabled" and an alert when attempting to click on a 4th element when 3 list elements have been selected.

I want to have the class added when the 3rd element is selected/clicked rather than what it is doing now and adding the class when the 4th element is trying to be selected.  I still want the alert to show when trying to select more than 3 elements of course.

How can I accomplish this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on('mousedown', 'ul.image_picker_selector li', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

        // get the number of items already selected:
        var ctSelected = $(this).siblings('.selected').length;

        if (ctSelected === 3) {
            $(this).closest('.image_picker_selector').find('li:not(.selected)').addClass('disabled');
            alert('You have already selected 3 items!' + ('\n') + 'You can undo a selection.');
        } else {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
        if (ctSelected < 3) {
            $(this).closest('.image_picker_selector').find('li:not(.selected)').removeClass('disabled');
        }

    });
})
</script>

    <ul class="thumbnails image_picker_selector">
    <li>
    <div class="thumbnail required">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q4-1.jpg"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="thumbnail selected required">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q4-2.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div class="thumbnail selected required">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q4-3.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="selected">
    <div class="thumbnail selected required">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q4-4.jpg">
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><div class="thumbnail required">
    <img class="image_picker_image" src="http://www.style-card.co.uk/id/assets/img/signup/Q4-5.jpg"></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply moving the `toggleClass()` function above your length calculation and comparison.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){

    $(document).on('mousedown', 'ul.image_picker_selector li', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

        // Do nothing if we are disabled
        if(  $(this).hasClass("disabled") ) return false;

        $(this).toggleClass('selected');

        // get the number of items already selected:
        var ctSelected = $(this).closest('.image_picker_selector').find('.selected').length;

        if (ctSelected > 3) {
            $(this).closest('.image_picker_selector').find('li:not(.selected)').addClass('disabled');
            alert('You have already selected 3 items!' + ('\n') + 'You can undo a selection.');
        } else if ( ctSelected == 3) {
            $(this).closest('.image_picker_selector').find('li:not(.selected)').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.image_picker_selector').find('li:not(.selected)').removeClass('disabled');
        } 

    });
});
</script>
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jNLJG/1/

Comment: That didnt seem to do it - it caused the class to be added in the same way (when trying to click a 4th list element) but not on the element that was tried to be clicked (if that makes sense..?)

Comment: The second edit, seemed to allow me to select all list elements now without adding a class or alert.....hmmm not sure what Im doing...

Comment: Part of the problem (I think) is in your HTML: you have `<DIV>`s with `selected` class -- those should apply to the `<li>` element instead, right?

Comment: If the li is selected, the div is selected too - I may have pasted some bad code.  You can get a better idea here of how it works http://style-card.co.uk/id/register/

Comment: Gotchya, take a look at the updated code & JS Fiddle and let me know if that does what you need it to. Part of the problem was the use of `siblings()` (which excludes `$(this)` element)

Comment: Thank you - it seems to work on the fiddle no problem, but when Ive used it on my page, it seems to go awry - any ideas?

Comment: after selecting 2, it adds the class and the alert doesnt seem to trigger..hmmm

Comment: How about this updated fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/jNLJG/2/ (note the change in the if/else at the bottom)

Comment: Ah im sorry it didnt seem to, I feel bad you are spending a lot of time on this!

Comment: What issues are you having coz his last fiddle update seems to do what you described in the question. http://jsfiddle.net/jNLJG/2/